# How can I clearly express that I worked for two different companies, within a period of time, but not at the same time?

Tags: word-choice

Here is what I've come up with so far:

- *In that year, I worked for two different companies, but not at the same time*. (This version doesn't feel right)
- *In that year, I worked for two different companies in succession.*
- *In that year, I worked for two different companies consecutively.*

So for example, I had one job, then quit it a few months later to work for another company.

Comment: Most people will assume that you did not work two jobs simultaneously, unless there's something different about the context.

Comment: I think "I worked for two different companies" says what you want it to say. Agreeing with @JohnFeltz, most will assume that was not done at the same time.

Comment: A usage note: You could say "In that year, I worked for two different companies consecutively." -- you would not use the "in". This is awkward partly because, as other mentioned, usually that is the assumption, but if you really wanted to disambiguate it wouldn't be unnatural to say it this way.

Comment: I worked alternately for CompanyA and CompanyB.

Comment: "During the year, I worked for two different companies."

Comment: @HotLicks Assuming 'LondonGuy' speaks BrE, "I worked alternately for CompanyA and CompanyB" would mean he worked first for Company A, then B, then back to A, then back to B, ... . AmE & BrE use "alternately" in different ways.

Comment: The assumption that someone works only a single job at a time depends entirely on what kind of job it is. It's very typical in the US for people in low-paying jobs to work multiple jobs. The assumption that the two jobs aren't simultaneous would depend, then, on the context (especially the type of job).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even simpler:

> In (year) I worked for Company A, then Company B.

Using "then" makes it clear that you are talking about a sequence of events.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

In year xxxx I worked for company A from Jan to May and then company B from Jun to Oct.

That is very simple and makes it very clear to the reader.